# Prepopulating Account name on Opportunity VF page

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, account

This is my VF page on Opportunity. Whenever I create an opportunity on Account page related list, account name should be prepopulated, otherwise it should be input lookup field.

VF page:

```
 <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CreateOppExtension"  >
      <apex:sectionHeader title="Opportunity Edit" subtitle="New Opportunity Edit"/>
      <apex:inputField label = "Account Name" value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}" required ='true'/>
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class CreateOppExtension 
{
    Opportunity opp {get;set;}
    String Owner {get;set;}
    public string accname{get;set;}  
    ApexPages.StandardController GstdController;

    public CreateOppExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {   
        GstdController= stdController;
        opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
        opp.Notes__c = 'Testing is done in this Profile,It should be visible for only PM-I record type.';
        // opp.AccountId=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('AccountId');
    }

    public List<Opportunity> getAccount() {
        List<Opportunity> Account = [Select AccountId FROM Opportunity];
        return Account;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        insert opp;
        return new PageReference('/'+opp.Id);
    }
}
```

Please let me know how it should get implemented.

Comment: You mean you are going to create opportunity by clicking on NEW button from Account layout (related list of opportunity) and Account name should be automatically populate ?

Comment: @ Nihar That is correct through related list new Opportunity button on Account layout. Well I can access my VF page through that button. Related Account name should get prepopluated

Comment: Have you overrode standard 'New' opportunity button with your VF page?

Comment: Yes i have @Edelrabe

Comment: Then the following should work:
    `<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CreateOppExtension"  >
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Opportunity Edit" subtitle="New Opportunity Edit" />
        
        <apex:form>
            <apex:inputField label="Account Name" value="{! Opportunity.AccountId }" required ='true' />
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>`

Comment: No It is not getting prepoulated account.Please check controller code as well. @Edelrabe

Answer (score 0):

First you have to override standard 'New' opportunity button with your custom VF page.

If you did this, the following code works just fine (I've just removed your `getAccount` method and wrapped `apex:inputField` with `apex:form` tag)

Updated page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CreateOppExtension"  >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Opportunity Edit" subtitle="New Opportunity Edit" />

    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField label="Account Name" value="{! Opportunity.AccountId }" required ='true' />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Updated controller:

```
public class CreateOppExtension 
{
    Opportunity opp {get;set;}
    String Owner {get;set;}
    public string accname{get;set;}  
    ApexPages.StandardController GstdController;

    public CreateOppExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {   
        GstdController= stdController;
        opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
        // opp.Notes__c = 'Testing is done in this Profile,It should be visible for only PM-I record type.';
        // opp.AccountId=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('AccountId');
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        insert opp;
        return new PageReference('/'+opp.Id);
    }
}
```

Proof:

[image]

Comment: For some reason it is not working for me.Is there any another alternative

Comment: Please find the updated code